# Login Elixir --Compilation error definitions with multiple clauses--

Tags: authentication, compilation, elixir

I'm trying to make a login in elixir, but when i put this code:

```
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
   model
   |> cast(params, ~w(email), [])
   |> validate_format(:email, ~r/@/)
end
```

I keep getting this error:

```
== Compilation error on file web/models/user.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/models/user.ex:25: definitions with multiple clauses and default values require a header. Instead of:

def foo(:first_clause, b \\ :default) do ... end
def foo(:second_clause, b) do ... end

one should write:

def foo(a, b \\ :default)
def foo(:first_clause, b) do ... end
def foo(:second_clause, b) do ... end

def changeset/2 has multiple clauses and defines defaults in one or more clauses
web/models/user.ex:25: (module)
(stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
(elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

I understand that i have to put a header, but i don´t know exactly how to fix it, anyone could explain me please?

Comment: Can you post the rest of that file? Looks like you're defining `changeset/2` twice.

Answer (score 2):

Your code likely looks something like this:

```
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
   # ...
end

def changeset(model, %{"some" => value}) do
   # ...
end
```

Elixir complains about this, because having multiple clauses with default values might result in ambiguities. To prevent such situations on a syntactic level, Elixir enforces using a separate function header for default values.

As the error message suggests, you need to add a separate function header defining the default value, then write your other clauses without default values:

```
# This is a function header, whose only purpose is to set
# default values that apply to all subsequent clauses
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty)

def changeset(model, params) do
   # ...
end

def changeset(model, %{"some" => value}) do
   # ...
end
```